Using view is making data retrieval much slower. Can anyone point out why this is happening?
So for my current project, there are two tables that hold multiple data i.e. certificate and logbook. These table have multiple duplicates of images in base64 format and to make them into a pdf later, I used a view named UserLogbookView that contains all the data. The certificate and logbook are parsed as a JSON data and saved in the database and later deserialized as required. The deserialization requires about 4 seconds whereas the data retrieval from the database from view takes about 7 minutes. Can someone please point out what I did wrong or what can be done to efficiently retrieve data. The program is written in C# using .NET and SQL server. Below, I've provided the SQL query, view class, dbcontext class and query to get the data.
SQL query :
CREATE VIEW UserLogbookView AS
SELECT
    u.UserId,
    u.Name,
    u.Gender,
    u.CandidateNumber,
    u.PhoneNumber,
    u.Email,
    u.Address,
    u.ImageUrl,
    u.UserName,
    u.SupervisorName,
    u.TrainingCenter,
    ui.UserInformationId,
    ui.PerformanceForm,
    ui.InternStartDate,
    ui.InternEndDate,
    ui.Abstract,
    ui.Marksheet,
    ui.StudentSignature,
    ui.InternshipCertificate,
    c.CourseId,
    c.CourseName,
    c.CourseCode,
    c.ShortCode,
    c.Duration,
    (SELECT CertificateImage FROM Certificate WHERE UserId = u.UserId FOR JSON PATH) AS Certificates,
    (SELECT [Name], LogStartDate, LogEndDate, [Shift], [Department], Section, Task, TaskImages, TaskImagesDescriptions, Observation FROM Logbook WHERE UserId = u.UserId FOR JSON PATH) AS Logbooks
FROM
    [User] u
LEFT JOIN
    UserInformation ui ON u.UserId = ui.UserId
LEFT JOIN
    Course c ON ui.CourseId = c.CourseId;



UserLogbookView.cs: namespace LogBook.Service.Models.View_Model_Logbook
{
    public class UserLogbookView
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string? Gender { get; set; }
        public string CandidateNumber { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string? Address { get; set; }
        public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? SupervisorName { get; set; }
        public string? TrainingCenter { get; set; }
        public string? UserInformationId { get; set; }
        public string? PerformanceForm { get; set; }
        public DateTime InternStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime InternEndDate { get; set; }
        public string? Abstract { get; set; }
        public string? Marksheet { get; set; }
        public string? StudentSignature { get; set; }
        public string? InternshipCertificate { get; set; } 
        public int? CourseId { get; set; }
        public string? CourseName { get; set; }
        public string? CourseCode { get; set; }
        public string? ShortCode { get; set; }
        public string? Duration { get; set; }
        public string? Certificates { get; set; }
        public string? Logbooks { get; set; }
    }

    public class CertificateViews
    {
        public string? CertificateImage { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogbookViews
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LogStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LogEndDate { get; set; }
        public string? Shift { get; set; }
        public string? Department { get; set; }
        public string? Section { get; set; }
        public string? Task { get; set; }
        public string? TaskImages { get; set; }
        public string? TaskImagesDescriptions { get; set; }
        public string? Observation { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserLogbookViewModel
    {
        public UserLogbookView UserDetails { get; set; }
        public List<CertificateViews> Certificates { get; set; }
        public List<LogbookViews> Logbooks { get; set; }
    }
}

DbContext.cs (part of it): modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogbookView>(a =>
{
    a.HasNoKey();
    a.ToView("UserLogbookView");
});

Query to retrieve data: var users = await _dbContext.UserLogbookView.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(a => a.UserId == userId)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);


How many rows are being returned that takes 7mins? And what is the total size of the payload? Data transfer can take time. How long does it take to run in SSMS? For SQL performance questions we need a) table definitions, b) index definitions and c) The execution plan using "Paste The Plan"

For each user, one single row is returned with payload averaging about 25Mb of data. In ssms, it takes about 3-5 seconds to return the data. The index defination time <500ms in each description and for table defination, i dont know what to see there. The only useful data there is length i.e >2000. As for the execution plan, https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyvIWFS3A is the link for it. It would really help me if you could look into it.

SSMS usually doesn't load the whole large column values, maybe that's the reason

[Edit] the clarifications into your question. The only thing I can see from your plan is that its using an index seek to get the certificate - so you can probably improve that with a better index, but thats only 10%. Otherwise I suspect its the amount of data you are puling. Try the same query without the JSON column and see how it performs.

It seems that the conversion to JSON data is taking up the time. Thank you so much for your feedback. Can you help me out with what to do instead of this now? My program logic has multiple duplicates of certificates (about 3-4) and logbooks( 24 entries )on the table mapped by the userId. How do i get the data now?

I think you're better off using proper queries that fetch related data instead of bundling it all up together in a json, the above code is not really native way of doing things

can you suggest me some method or alternatives to approach it correctly? I really need all the data of a user bundled together to create the pdf.

what happens if you query the view direct in SSMS ? Is it still slow ?

I'd suspect something client-side to be honest. Wait stats in this query plan indicate ASYNC_NETWORK_IO so it may just be a slow/poor connection, but it may also be some kind of locking problem, or other EF Core issue. I suggest you benchmark just the actual query, without any other side effects.

Read about how to do joins in EF
